# Pass in and use Type via a function argument?

Tags: rust

I have a simple function where I pass in a `reqwest::Response`, and have it parse and return some JSON (using Serde).

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    field:String,
}

fn parse(response: reqwest::Response) -> Result<Foo, Error> {
    response.json::<Foo>().await?
}
```

I want to make this generic, so the type isn't hardcoded, and I can pass in the type. Here is some meta code for an example:

```
fn parse(response: reqwest::Response, type: TYPE) -> Result<TYPE, Error> {
    response.json::<TYPE>().await?
}
```

Is this possible in Rust? How would I pass in the `Foo` type? (or maybe one of the Traits?) and use it in the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In rust [generics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics.html) are represented as `<T>`. In your case, `T` must implement `DeserializeOwned` in order to be deserialized from the json response, so you can add that as a [bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/generics/bounds.html) for `T`:

```rust
fn parse<T: DeserializeOwned>(response: Response) -> Result<T, Error> {
    response.json::<T>().await?
}
```

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer to make that explicit.